# Polygonize Specific DN

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, polygonize

I am using QGIS 2.18.5.

I have a very large raster with DN values of interest (3) and others which I have no interest in at all (0,1,2). To prevent polygonising the entire raster which would take a number of hours, is it possible to selectively process values which match DN = '3'?

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Raster Calculator** to create a new raster containing only cells which have the value `3`, leaving the rest as nodata by using the following expression:

```
"raster@1" / ("raster@1" = 3)
```

You can then polygonize the output which *should* dramatically decrease processing time.